# Find the area of this figure using polar coordinates (possible textbook mistake)

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

I am required to find the area of this region using polar coordinates:

[image]

My setup is

$$
A = \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\phi} \left[ R \sin(\theta) \right]^2 d\theta = \frac{R^2}{4} \int_{0}^{\phi} \left[ 1-\cos(2\theta) \right] = \frac{R^2}{4} \left[ \theta - \sin(2 \theta) \right] \bigg|_{0}^{\phi} = \frac{R^2 \phi}{4} - \frac{R^2 \sin(2 \phi)}{8}
$$

The answer on the textbook is

$$
A = R^2\phi - \frac{R^2\sin(2\phi)}{2}
$$

Am I making a mistake somewhere?

Comment: what is the equation of the curve depicted in the figure?

Comment: @K.K.McDonald it is not given (so from my point of view we can assume it's a circle with radius $R/2$ and center $(0,R/2)$.

Comment: Ok so it seems that assumption was wrong.

Comment: anyway I'm Happy now that u got your answer  \-(^v^)-/

Comment: @K.K.McDonald thank you =)

Comment: no problem bro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to check that for $\varphi = \pi,\pi/2 $ your answer tallies as a semi-circle and full circle of diameter $R$. The text book is wrong.

His error is because of assuming the label $R$ for diameter as radius.

Comment: ah ok so, let's say that picture could be more clear (stating that the radius is actually $R$ and not $R/2$) - that way we can arrive at the desired answer, right?

Comment: No. that will increase confusion ( you swapped them). It should be mentioned that $R$ is diameter. Best is to use another symbol$D$ or $d$.

Comment: Actually $R$ is the radius (that provides the answer the book expects). I am the one that assumed that the radius was $R/2$. So the picture could be more clear, but I'm the one that made the mistake. Thanks for pointing that out for me. Cheers.

Comment: Oh,OK! that was your picture!  Anyway now you can put it all into order.

Comment: what do you mean about putting in order? Do you mean editing the post?

Comment: No, may be send a msg to text author that $R$ stands for radius only shown in a sketch you gave.  But if you feel it is your interpretation that caused it, its ok to ignore it silently :).

Comment: ah I see. Yes for this one I guess I'll just take a step back =)